# Two ViewScoped CDI beans, one injected into the other, and one JSF page: Instances differ

Tags: jsf, cdi, view-scope

I have two ViewScoped CDI beans A and B and one JSF page. One bean (B) is injected into the other (A). Both are accessed directly from the JSF page. After some debugging I found that the instance of B injected into A is not the same as the instance of B accessed from the JSF page.

A:

```
package newpackage;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named
@ViewScoped
public class A implements Serializable {
  @Inject
  B b;

  public int getValueB() {
    int bb = b.getValueB();
    return bb; // <- break here
  }
}
```

and B:

```
package newpackage;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named
@ViewScoped
public class B implements Serializable {
  Logger logger = Logger.getAnonymousLogger();
  int randomNumber;

  public B() {
    logger.info("Constructor B called");
  }

  @PostConstruct
  public void init() {
    SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
    randomNumber = random.nextInt();

    logger.log(Level.INFO, "init B called: {0}", randomNumber);
  }

  public int getValueB() {
    return randomNumber;
  }
}
```

and the JSF page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
  </head>
  <h:body>
    <h:outputText value="#{a.valueB}"/>
    <h:outputText value="#{b.valueB}"/>
  </h:body>
</html>
```

The instance of B injected into A (A.b) is not the same as the instance of B accessed directly from the JSF page (b.valueB). My expectation was they would be the same, since they're accessed at the same time on the same page. Is there an explanation for this? Was my expectation wrong?

Set a breakpoint at the line with the comment 'break here'. Now observe something peculiar: The value of the variable *bb* is a big random number; however, the value of A.b.randomNumber is 0. How can that be?

Comment: from which package is he @ViewScoped taken from?

Comment: import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;

Comment: Your Jsf Version?

Comment: How do you know they are different and how they are accessed the same time? [mcve] please

Comment: And including information about the container you're using would be helpful.

Comment: I have glassfish 4.1.2 and mojarra 2.2.13.

Comment: @Kukeltje: In the debugger: The memory address was different and a value I was inspecting was too. By the 'same time' I just meant during the time the page under question was loaded in the browser.

Comment: Your code does not show 'same time' access, that is where the clarification should be. E.g. does `a.getValueA()` effectively do a `return b.getValueB()`? How is this value 'set'... etc... Again... [mvce] otherwise helps stops here unfortunately

Comment: @Kukeltje: I've turned the code snippets into a minimal example.

Comment: I guess you are using `h:body` instead of `body` tag

Comment: @perissf: You mean `h:head` instead of `head` since `body` works in most of the cases and a missing  `h:head` can result in a lot of problems

Comment: in a, implement a `getValueB() {return b.getValueB())` and add a `<h:outputText value="#{a.valueB}"/>`. What does that show? Keep in mind that 'memory addresses' are dangerous to look at since cdi uses proxies!)

Comment: @Kukeltje: sure, thanks for the clarification

Comment: @Kukeltje: I implemented a.valueB and it prints a 'B'. The memory addresses of B in a.valueB and b.valueB are still different.

Comment: Memory addresses of the strings?Create a random value of b in a @PostConstruct annotated method instead of a fixed value, how often is that called. Print those. Are they identical? Add constructors, how often are those called? Please do some basic debugging.

Comment: Thanks for the hints, I've updated the code. As to your questions: I meant the memory addresses of the instances of B. The constructor of B is called twice; the @PostConstruct method however only once. The outputed random numbers are identical.

Comment: Please note that I've also updated my question at the bottom.

Comment: _"The outputed random numbers are identical."_ Then everything works as expected... ! _"The value of the variable bb is a big random number; however, the value of A.b.randomNumber is 0. How can that be?"_ Noticed this to once in my project. This is a debugger/cdi/injection related issue I think. 0 is the default value for an int and the debugger does not resolve the method call in a good way and shows 'wrong' information.